# Missing trend line

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add a trend line to the historical values of the S&P500, but when I try to add the trend line it doesn't appear, only the S&P500 values appear in the chart. ("Dato" means "Date" in Norwegian.)

Here's my code:

```
##################### Load the data

df = pd.read_csv("SP500.csv", delimiter=r",", names = ["Date","Open", "High",
                                      "Low", "Close", "S&P500",
                                      "Volume"])

df = df.drop(columns=['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume'])

df["Dato"] = df["Date"]

df2 = pd.read_excel("OSEBX.xlsx", names = ["Date", "OSEBX"])

df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
df2.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

df3 = df.join(df2)
df["Dato"] = pd.to_datetime(df3["Dato"])

################################ Graph


t = np.array(range(0, len(df["Dato"])))

x = np.array(df3["OSEBX"])
y = np.array(df3["S&P500"])

plt.scatter(t,x, s=1)

z = np.polyfit(x, t, 1)

p = np.poly1d(z)

plt.plot(x,p(x),"bs", linewidth=20)


plt.show()
```

Comment: Plot of (t,x) vs plot of (x,p(x))?

Comment: I've scattered the values of the OSEBX, plt.scatter(t, x, s=1), But the trend is missing.

Comment: But `t` is an integer range and `x` is the "y" in the `x(t)` plot. In your trend you have `p(x)` on the "y" axis and `x` on the "x" axis, and `p(x)` seems to be a fit to `t(x)`. Isn't it? You may have your `x` and `t` swapped in either plot.

Answer (score 1):

```
#Thanks to Andreas Deak I found a solution:

t = np.array(range(0, len(df3["Dato"])))

x = np.array(df3["OSEBX"])
y = np.array(df3["S&P500"])

plt.plot(t, x, linewidth=0.5, color="b")

z = np.polyfit(t, x, 1)
p = np.poly1d(z)
plt.plot(t, p(t),"r--", linewidth=0.5)
plt.show()
```